# Why does meta directing group also pull electrons from ortho and para positions?

Tags: resonance, nucleophilic-substitution

I have been taught that electron withdrawing groups are meta directing. If it cannot modulate electron density over ortho and para positions during resonance, why does it help in nucleophilic substitution in a aromatic ring in which the leaving group is situated at ortho/para positions?

Comment: Draw canonical structures...

Comment: @Zenix sir are you asking me to give you a diagram or Are you asking me to draw and check.If you are asking me for a example, 1 chloro 4 nitro benzene undergoes nucleophilic substitution more easily than chloro benzene.

Comment: So? Draw the reaction with transition state and paste it into your question.

Comment: I was asking you to draw and conclude, also we use the terminology of "directing" groups in EAS, ArSN (your example) are a whole different reactions, you are mixing two different things...

Comment: @Karl Sir it does not allows me to paste the photo.

Comment: @Zenix sir it is not allowing me to upload picture to this question.

Comment: Don't use mobile app, rather use cellphone's browser (in case you are using  cellphone)....

Comment: @Zenix Ok sir.Thank you for your response.